# 2-order curve main axis transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have to do main axis transformation this curve:

$3x^{2} -8xy-3y^{2}=c $

I did transformation and got this:
$\frac{5x^{2}}{c}-\frac{5y^{2}}{c}=1$

I think it should be correct. Now I have to find out which plot I will get for $c=1$, $c=0$ and $c=-2$.

For $c=1$ and $c=-2$ I will for sure get hyperbola. But with $c=0$. I will get $0=1$. Am I making mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you really have to divide c on both sides. $5x^{'2}-5y^{'2
}=c$ [if the calculation is right] would be just fine, and you won't get 0=1.